# search 4-5 bytes sequence in big file

Tags: performance, file, search, language-agnostic, indexing

I have file ~ 1.5GB
I need to find in this file 3 billion sequences of bytes. One sequence may be 4 or 5 bytes.
Find the first position, or to make sure that such a sequence in the file no.
How to do it fastest?

RAM limit on computer - 4GB

Comment: Maybe you could expand on the scenario more? 3 billion sequences in ~1.5 billion bytes probably has a huge overlap. Do you need to find the position of those sequences? Or simply whether they exist at all?

Comment: Get get more RAM? It's quite cheap these days.

Comment: Are you doing BLAST http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAST ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`grep`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep). It's highly optimized for finding things in large files.
If that's not an option, read about the [Boyer-Moore algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) it uses and implement it yourself. It'll take a lot of tweaking to reproduce the same speed `grep` has though.

Comment: 3 billion independent runs, even a very fast algorithm to be slow.

Comment: Who said you need to run it 3 billion times? `grep` supports regular expressions, which support logical OR queries. Even if ORing 3 billion terms is difficult, you could at least chunk it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Preprocessing.

I think you should just create an `Index`, make a run through the file, recording the first instance of every unique 4 byte sequence. Store the 4 byte sequence and the first occurring position in a different file, sorted by the byte sequence.

Using a simple binary search on the Index file will efficiently find your sequence.

You could be more clever and use hashing to reduce the search to O(1).

Comment: sequence may be 5 bytes. In this case, the first position of 4-byte sequence is not enough.

Comment: What do you think, how much will be the size of the index?

Comment: It will depend on how many times your 4-5 bytes sequences repeat...The higher the repetitions the smaller the index size. Worst case (if all sequence are present), 255^5 (~4228250625) (All combinations of bytes of length 5).

Comment: You'll need to make records for both of 4 and 5 bytes.

Comment: and for any uniq sequence need store postion in file. How to store such a large index?

Comment: Fixed Length Recrods in a Flat File with Random Access or Use a DB ? :\

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Searchlight search engine.

This program allows multiple sequences of up to 10 ASCII bytes to be stored within a single file.  You then point it at a file, directory, file of filenames, file of directory names, arraylist of filenames or an arraylist of directory names and away it goes!!

Furthermore, it reports the file byte position/offset of each sequence found.